# How to do an ICSP for an ATtiny 85

Tags: attiny, bootloader, attiny85

I know that we can simply buy one of those ICSPs on the web, but my problem is that I am already going to buy a good quantity of hardware on the web and in my country those chips are quite expensive, so I thought that I could build one with what I already have.

Is there a way to build one? I was thinking of loading a few bytes manually for a bootloader and let it load a ROM on the chip. I was also thinking of loading the ROM from a pendrive.

Does someone know how to do that?

Comment: You can use many different devices, including some USB serial chips or an Arduino as an ISP programmer. And with some PC software that can do ISP programming via the device you use. You should do a bit more research if whatever you happen to already have can do it.

Comment: I found some more information on the datasheet and it's impossible to a beginner like me do a programmer, so probably I will do some way around here. I still don't know how I will implement that but I know that it's not practical to do a programmer by myself. The link to the datasheet where I found info about doing it: [ATtiny25/45/85 Automotive - 8-bit AVR Microcontroller with 2/4/8K Bytes In-SystemProgrammable Flash](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7598_Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATtiny25-45-85_Datasheet.pdf). Section 20.6.

Answer (score 1):

For the ATtiny chips there are a number of simple direct serial port programming designs available using minimal hardware, you would just need to download the serial port driver.  Here are two examples with an RS232 type serial input.

http://electronics-diy.com/avr-programmer.php

https://sites.google.com/site/ahmedabdien89/Embedded-Systems/avrprogrammer

The popular USB port ISP can be purchased, (relatively low cost) or built from scratch if desired. The whole schematic is available as well as all other needed resources. (For this version you would need to program the chip used on the board).

USB programmer, (buy complete):
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11801

Full Schematic:
http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/AVR/Tiny_Programmer.pdf

Resource page:
https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/tiny-avr-programmer-hookup-guide/resources--going-further

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Arduino as an ISP programmer by just adding a few wires...

https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/arduino-isp/ArduinoISP

You could use this to program a bootloader into your chip a subsequently use that to self program the chip without any hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Worth having a look at the David Mellis Arduino board support package for ATTiny85 which has good content to learn from  http://highlowtech.org/?p=1706 and https://github.com/damellis/attiny